# How to find the elements with data attribute and ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to find out an element ID in the same sentence?

```
<div class="test">
 <input id="999" type="text" data-test="2">
</div>

Example
 $('.test').find('[data-test="2"] #999)
```

I tried to find a specific input in my html code, but this input exists many times with the same id value, the only difference is the attr "data-test" (the number is incremental)

Any help for this?

Comment: If the input exists many times, you should use a `class` instead of `id`

Comment: Get rid of the space. The space means that `#999` is a descendant of `[data-test=2]`.

Comment: "this input exists many time with the same id value" ?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Probably worth a read: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an example, problem is `999` is not valid for an ID, and will not work in a query selector.

**Remember** an `id` should be unique also, so I am not sure why you need to combine?

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.test');

const child1 = parent.querySelector('[data-test="2"]');
const child2 = parent.querySelector('[data-test="3"]');

console.log(child1.value);
console.log(child2.value);
```

```html
<div class="test">
 <input class="demo1" type="text" data-test="2" value="input1">
 <input class="demo1" type="text" data-test="3" value="input2">
</div>
```

Comment: oh this maybe help me . is because the html always use unique id for the fields, but now need add same fields but in other sections in the html

Answer (score 0):

If your markup is valid, `id`s need to be unique for the entire page. So you can skip the data part of the selector.

```
$('#999')
```

Will do the trick in a valid document. However if you use incremental numbers for various elements your `id`s are likely not unique. It would be better to use classes in this case.